# How can I acces Axis1 webservice from another project's jsp?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, javabeans, axis

I have two dynamic web projects in my eclipse: `project1` and `project2`.

`project1` have an axis1 webservice, that I can access within its jsp through the bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="cAwt4WsProxyid" scope="session" class="DefaultNamespace.Awt4WsProxy" />
```

How can I access `project`1 webservice from `project2` jsp's?

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing to the Axis Service using:

`<jsp:useBean id="cAwt4WsProxyid" scope="session" class="DefaultNamespace.Awt4WsProxy" />`

Just have access to the Class as a JavaBean component. You don't need to deploy an Axis service to do that.

If you want to call to the Axis webservice from another project (or from the same) you'll need to use SOAP protocol.